# Any way to run a function when a gulp task is finished

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have many gulp tasks in my gulpfile, and I need to run a function after each task is done.

I handled my task registration like this:

```
var registerTask = function (taskName, dependencies, todo) {
  if (isProduction) {
    gulp.task(taskName, dependencies, todo);
  } else {
    var prefixedTaskName = '_' + taskName;

    // the original task registers here with another name
    gulp.task(prefixedTaskName, dependencies, todo);

    // register my task to do after the original task is done
    gulp.task(taskName, [prefixedTaskName], myRepeatedFunction);
  }
}
```

and I register my tasks like this:

```
registerTask('foo', [], function () {
  gulp
    .src()
    .pipe()
    ...
})
```

BUT this makes my terminal dirty with the logs (underscored task names):

```
[15:54:17] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/xxx/gulpfile.js
[15:54:17] Starting '_default'...
[15:54:17] Starting '_remove-source-map'...
[15:54:17] Starting '_fontastic'...
[15:54:28] Finished '_fontastic' after 11 s
[15:54:28] Starting 'fontastic'...
[15:54:28] Finished 'fontastic' after 125 μs
[15:54:28] Starting '_js-hint'...
[15:54:28] Finished '_remove-source-map' after 11 s
[15:54:28] Starting 'remove-source-map'...
[15:54:28] Finished 'remove-source-map' after 59 μs
[15:54:28] Starting '_sass'...
[15:54:33] Finished '_sass' after 4.19 s
[15:54:33] Starting 'sass'...
[15:54:33] Finished 'sass' after 21 μs
[15:54:33] Finished '_js-hint' after 5.11 s
[15:54:33] Starting 'js-hint'...
[15:54:33] Finished 'js-hint' after 18 μs
[15:54:33] Starting '_js'...
[15:54:50] Finished '_js' after 17 s
[15:54:50] Starting 'js'...
[15:54:50] Finished 'js' after 17 μs
[15:54:50] Finished '_default' after 32 s
[15:54:50] Starting 'default'...
[15:54:50] Finished 'default' after 19 ms
```

I'm looking for a better way to do the same thing without the dirty logs (I don't want to use --silent)

if there was a callback in a `gulp.task` I could do the same thing in a nice way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gulp inherits its task running capabilities from [`orchestrator`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator) which provides an [`.on()`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratoronevent-cb) function to register event listeners.

Say you have a task `foo` and want to run a function after task `foo` has finished. You can do that like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('foo', function() {
  // do task stuff
});

gulp.on('task_stop', function(evt) {
  if (evt.task == 'foo') {
    // do stuff after task foo has finished
  }
});
```

For this to work you **have** to make sure your async tasks [are properly signalling completion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support). That means don't forget to return your streams or to call the callback function in your async tasks!